# Did the Buddha cover colorblindness in his teachings?

Tags: practice, metta, lay-practices, society

Is "[Racial color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_color_blindness)" covered in the Buddha's teaching? What would be the closest Buddhist concept that covers it? Is there a scripture that teaches colorblindness?

Could it have originated from the Buddha's teaching, Christianity, both or somewhere else? Does anyone know what Thích Nhất Hạnh taught MLK about colorblindness?

Comment: Do you mean anti-racism? I closed this question as a duplicate assuming it's about racism. If it's not, I'll reopen it. Possibly duplicate of [Buddhism and Racism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/39378/471).

Comment: Come on, don't close my gosh darn question down. It's not about racism. It's about colorblindness. A totally separate concept.

Comment: like why is your heart green?  like that of course i assume...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142122/discussion-on-question-by-lowbrow-did-the-buddha-cover-colorblindness-in-his-t).

Comment: What is "colorblindness"? The biological condition of not being able to identify colors correctly? What do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness

Comment: @Remyla Yes that's the normal meaning. Given that the OP is asking about MLK etc., ruben2020 was asking Lowbrow whether that's meant literally/biologically, or instead meant metaphorically/sociologically -- e.g. something like [the second definition here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color-blind) i.e. "treating all people the same regardless of race".

Comment: @ ruben2020 It means not treating someone good or bad just because they are a different color.

Comment: It represents our heart.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_color_blindness

Comment: The question about "the origin of color blindness" -- i.e. about the history of the US Supreme Court decisions, and whether they could have originated from religious doctrines -- might be askable on https://law.stackexchange.com/ or https://history.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

From [racial color blindness (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_color_blindness):

> A color-blind racial ideology can be defined as holding the belief
> that an individual's race or ethnicity should not influence how that
> individual is treated in society. This is further divided into two
> dimensions, color evasion and power evasion. Color evasion is the
> belief that people should not be treated differently on the basis of
> their color, while power evasion posits that systemic advantage based
> on color should have no influence on what people can accomplish, and
> accomplishments are instead based solely on one's own work
> performance.

This sutta quote still covers it best, I feel:

> “Don’t ask about birth, ask about conduct;
> for any kindling can kindle a flame.
> A steadfast sage, even though from a low class family,
> is a thoroughbred checked by conscience.
> [SN 7.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn7.9/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Any kindling, any piece of wood, can be used to kindle a flame.

Don't discriminate the type of wood or kindling.

Essentially color blindness.

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha was anti-caste and pro-feminism. Keep in mind this is still limited by the world of India 2600 years ago. The caste system is comparable to racism.

When someone ordained, their caste as a lay person became irrelevant. A monk who was a brahmin (priestly caste) and a monk who was a worker, were treated the same.

[MN 93 - The Buddha critiquing the caste system.](https://suttacentral.net/mn93/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

If a woman/girl had been married and wanted to ordain, they could become a full monk (bhikkhuni) in two years. So, a formerly married girl as young as 12 could become a novice monk and then at 14, she could become a full female monk (bhikkhuni). But people had to be at least 20 years old to become a full male monk (bhikkhu).